# Flutter - How do I correctly handle go_router, with redirects and context.pop()

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I'm using `go_router` and trying to handle auth using redirects, so if a user isn't logged in they go to the `inviteCode` screen. This all works well.

My flow is:
`invite screen -> home -> profile`

The `profile` screen has a `log out` button on it.

My problem is that when the user logs out they return to the `inviteCode` screen correctly, but if they press the android back button, they end up at the `home` screen which should only be access when authenticated. (Note the same happens if I add a button with `context.pop()` onto that original screen)

Here's my `GoRouter` config

```
    /// Forwards diagnostic messages to the dart:developer log() API.
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    errorBuilder: (context, state) => ErrorPage(state),
    initialLocation: '/',
    redirect: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
      User user = context.read(userStateProvider);
      if (!user.isLoggedIn) {
        return '/welcome/inviteCode';
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    },

    routes: <RouteBase>[
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return const HomeScreen();
        },
        routes: <RouteBase>[
          GoRoute(
            path: 'profile',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const ProfileScreen();
            },
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: 'welcome/inviteCode',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const InviteCodeScreen();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
```

Does anyone know what I should be doing to stop this happening. It feels like a pretty common usage pattern that I'd imagine lots of other apps use with it, but I'm finding the documentation hard to follow/outdated

Comment: So, you don't want the user to be able to go back once it's logged? I don't understand what do you need exactly

Comment: If you log in, go to your profile and log out, I don't want the back button / pop to take you back to the home (ie logged in) main page when you are logged out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the expected behavior based on your routes hierarchy structure. GoRouter uses declarative routing (aka Flutter Navigator 2.0). Navigating to a destination using declarative routing will replace the current stack of "screens" with the stack of "screens" configured to be displayed for the destination route.

On your routes configuration the route with path "welcome/inviteCode" is a child of the route of "/". When you navigate using "go" to "/welcome/inviteCode" it will build the stack of routes bellow:

```
|- HomeScreen  
|  |- InviteCodeScreen
```

Which means that if you "pop back" from that `InviteCodeScreen` screen it will show the `HomeScreen` screen, since it's the page that is "bellow" it in the stack of routes.

If you want you `InviteCodeScreen` to be a *root* route, you shall move it up in the routes configuration hierarchy and put it at the same level as `HomeScreen`:

```dart
routes: <RouteBase>[
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return const HomeScreen();
        },
        routes: <RouteBase>[
          GoRoute(
            path: 'profile',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const ProfileScreen();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      GoRoute(
            path: '/welcome/inviteCode',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const InviteCodeScreen();
            },
          )
    ],
```

**IMPORTANT**: The path is now `/welcome/inviteCode` instead of just `welcome/inviteCode` since it is no longer a child route of `/`

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the answer, it really helped me understand some fundamentals that I don't feel the documentation makes clear 

Comment: Indeed this key concept is not very clear in the official docs.